# PTIJ: Halachic implications of not accepting the cab ride

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100731/ptij-what-are-my-options-if-a-server-rejects-a-post-or-put-request) question.

Is there an obligation to enter the cab that one has called while in Israel? Does it matter whether the driver is a religious Jew or not? Can you reject a [Gett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gett), or even a [Gett Mehadrin](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/miriamberger/what-a-kosher-taxi-app-in-jerusalem-really-looks-like) or are you forced to accept its ride?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: There's nothing '**Purim**' here.

Comment: @msh210 then you and I celebrate Purim and divorces very differently.

Comment: @msh210 What’s not Purim about asking about hailing a Gett?

Answer (score 0):

One need not accept a Gett unless it is from someone who you may marry according to the Torah, because otherwise the kiddushin was ineffective in the first place. So in Israel you should make sure to reject any driver who is not of the same gender as you.

(Note: this may be misinterpreted and you should do it at your own risk)

There is another possible issue, which is of shelichut. If someone else sends you a Gett, you may be forced to accept it if they could marry you mi'deorita even if the driver is of your own gender.

I'm told there's a new app called NoGett which forbids shlichut in its terms of service, sorts by gender and even has Kohen and Kohen Gadol settings for leniency. A baal nefesh should be stringent to use this new app.

Comment: When I was in Eretz Yisrael, I just called a cab company, specifically not a Gett. Just remove myself from all Sefeikos entirely.